# How to use YAML "Knit:" that is not at the start of the Rmd in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am having an issue with using "Knit:" in my YAML for when I knit a Rmd in R Studio. I assumed that like "Title:" or "Author:", "Knit:" could be referenced at any point in the Rmd by using the following:

```
---
Knit:
---
```

However, I only seem to be able to get this working if "Knit:" is placed at the start of the Rmd.

The issue is that my script creates automatic export folders where I would like the HTML output to be stored once the knit has been completed.

For example:

````
---
Title: "My Title"
Author: "Me"
Output: html_document
---

```{r automatic_export_generation}
code to automatically create an export folder
```

---
knit: (function(input,encoding) {
 rmarkdown::render(
  input,
  output_file = paste0(file.path(rstudioapi::getActiveProject()),AutomaticExport))
 })
---
````

It works in this configuration:

````
---
Title: "My Title"
Author: "Me"
Output: html_document
knit: (function(input,encoding) {
     rmarkdown::render(
      input,
      output_file = paste0(file.path(rstudioapi::getActiveProject()),"/Test_File/test.html"))
     })
---

```{r automatic_export_generation}
code to automatically create an export folder
```
````

But this is not what I need as the automatic file generation comes after a number of validation checks that have knit_exit applied to ensure my team does not run data through that is missing key variables and unnecessary export files are not created.

Is there a workaround for this so that I can export the HTML file to the same place that all of the CSVs are being exported to in the automatic file generation?